# Scrapy: Scrape data from a get request

Tags: python, xml, request, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from https://www.seloger.com with scrapy.
But when I try the view(response) in the shell, some of the response is missing.

When I opened the chrome dev tools, I analyzed the network, and realized that the data I'm searching for comes from a get request where the response to it is a json file that contains the data I need. But the request fails due to

Is there anyway to do a manual get request in scrapy to get the json file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the request usually when making an XHR request it is important to identify a couple of headers in this case it looks like only Accept header. So what you want to do is something like this.

First have the spider visit the home page. It will load in all the cookies through the set-cookie headers that it gets sent. Then make a request like the following.

```
scrapy.Request(theurl, callback=self.parsejson, headers={
 'Accept': 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
 'User-Agent': 'My UA'
})

import json
def parsejson(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    item['foo'] = data['bar']
    yield item
```

PS: If you use firefox you can edit and resend the request and keep taking out parameters to find out the minimum headers it will accept. Usually its just a matter of telling it that you're expecting back JSON.

Comment: Yeah many sites dont require cookies just that you set the right headers for the type of request your making. Sometimes Content-Type i think matters too or XRequestedWith XMLHttpRequest is common to see.

Answer (score 0):

A GET Request should be structured similar to a standard URL you visit. Instead of the URL returning a nice HTML page though, it will (in this case) return JSON text. scrapy however, does have a nice set of functions to do this:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Here's an example from that page:

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
                           cookies=[{'name': 'currency',
                                    'value': 'USD',
                                    'domain': 'example.com',
                                    'path': '/currency'}])
```

The text that's returned from example.com in this case will be handled by the `parse` function for the spider, but you can set your own callback function.